# error in installing google api python client

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdata, google-api-python-client

I'm installing google api python client on python 3 using pip from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client).

But getting the following error:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

I already installed microsoft windows sdk 7.1 and net framework 4.0.

But it's not working.

Please check [the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZk8U.png) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdata is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory) and does not have support for Python 3.x in the first place. Use any of [these](https://developers.google.com/products) APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Shobhit Bhatnagar, try this one - `pip install -e git+https://github.com/dvska/gdata-python3#egg=gdata`